# fragments or database.. what is preferable?

Tags: android, database, listview, android-fragments

In my application I have listed 10 school names using a `listview`.  By selecting a school name the corresponding information should be displayed on screen, information such as an image, some description about that school, contact no., etc.

Should I use fragments to define info about each school. If yes then which fragment should I use and which method to be overridden?

Can storing this information in a database be the solution for this?

Can I get some examples related to this?

```
 package com.example.mayurijoshi.puneclassified1;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class school extends ListActivity {

    //Defining android ListView
    ListView mListView;

    //Elements that will be displayed in android ListView
    String[] schools = new String[]{"School 1", "School 2", "School 3",
            "School 4", "School 5", "School 6", "School 7", "School 8", "School 9", School 10};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_school);

        mListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listschool);

        //Declaring Array adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> schoolAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, schools);

        //Setting the android ListView's adapter to the newly created adapter
        mListView.setAdapter(schoolAdapter);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                int itemPosition = position;


                String itemValue = (String) mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);


                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SchoolDesc.class);


                Here we will pass the previously created intent as parameter
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_school, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are not an alternative to databases. Fragments are for displaying content and databases are for saving your data persistently so that you can access the same data even after closing and opening all again.

Here, you need to use two activities. One for displaying the list view. And another for displaying individual school details after you tap one school row. When you tap a school row, pass either school ID or name as an extra with the intent and start the second activity. The second activity can select the corresponding school details from database based on the ID or name and then display those details.

But, for this, you will need to create and populate the database in some way before trying to display the content . let me know if you need any more clarification. :)

Comment: so here should i use switch case in 2nd activity to select the corresponding school based on ID..?

Comment: I am not sure how you whole code structure is, but assuming that you have a database, you have to run a select query on the database with the ID field and then fetch all values and display. Please accept the answer of it has helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

> so here, should i use fragments to define info. about each school.

Fragments are UI portions or lightweight activity.And Yes you should use fragment to display such data. And the code you have written to open new activity `SchoolDesc.class` will work also. Overriding methods is almost same as Activity. You shoud check the official guide [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/fragments.html).

As to the part of database, Of course you can use it to store information and images using sqllite. But fragments are not used to store or define any data, only to get data from files or databases and show them.